# How to format string to right and left justify while writing to file in scala?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write two strings to a file:

var str1 = "this is"
var str2 = "a good day"

such that str1 should be written right justified and str2 left justified.

I read that it works something like this:

```
fw.write("%" + str1)
fw.write("%-" + str2)
```

But, it's not giving me the expected result. Why is that?

EDIT:

```
val fw = new FileWriter("results.txt", true) ;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "right justified"? If you mean it should end at a fixed column (while "left justified" starts at column 0), you need to specify what column it should end on somewhere (i.e. your line length)

Comment: What is your specific use case? Do all strings you output fit into one line? I think that plain-text files are not suited well for (complex) text formatting. Maybe your programm could output Latex code or one of the "Office-formats". For example, [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) allows you to programmatically generate "Microsoft Word"-files.

Comment: I just mean right/ left justified as is meant in MSWord or something. I know that there is something like Scala formatting, but I can't figure how to use it.

Comment: I am new to Scala and don't understand all that you've written at all.

Comment: What do you mean by **Scala formatting**? I wasn't really referring to Scala in specific as there are general problems to your question. Firstly, as **Paul** already mentioned: What is the "right end" of your text file? A plain-text file does not really have a right end. And then: Say we specify the right end to be at column `80`; What should happen if a string is `81` characters long? Should it break lines? If yes, where? Or is `str2` guaranteed to be less than `80` characters long in our example? By the way: What is the **type** of `fw` in your example code?

Comment: @KuluLimpa I meant something like this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/Development/StringformattingRightjustifyandLeftjustify.htm

Comment: @Paul It should only print 30 words from str1 and 30 words from str2.

Comment: @LindaSu Thank you for the clarification. It wasn't clear to me, whether `fw.write` was supposed to provide string formatting, and what you were trying to achieve. I'm sorry, if I was confusing you. In that case, **Suztomo**'s answer should work for you? Similarly, your linked Python-example would translate to `val integerValue = 4237;println("Right justify integer (%8d)".format(integerValue));println("Left justify integer  (%-8d)\n".format(integerValue))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"+" only concatenates two strings. Try format method.

```
fw.write("%-10s".format(str2))
```